# Slack Officiel SDK - Can not fetch newly added channel

Tags: java, kotlin, slack-api

I can not fetch two newly added channels using slack's Converstaion API. I can fetch all the channels, except the two channels that I have newly added.

**Example**: I have three channels in my workspace

- test-result
- slack-bot
- local-test

I created `test-result` a long time ago, and I can find it. But I can not find the two that I created yesterday.

This is my code.

```
val client = Slack.getInstance().methods()
val conversationList = client.conversationsList { r -> r.token(slackApiToken) }
conversationList.channels.find { it.name == "slack-bot" }
```

I have invited my bot in both of the channels. Do I need more configuration?

#### Update

**slack-bot** is name of the channel.

`conversationList.channels` contains all the channels that I knew, exists except the two that I have recently created.

Comment: Doesn't this look for a channel named "slack-bot"? Surely it's a channel with another name, in which "slack-bot" is a member?

Comment: "slack-bot" is name of the channel. And the bot can not finding it. @k314159 I update my question

Comment: What does `client.conversationList` return?

Comment: You might want to update your question with more information. How did you set it up, what is the call you are doing? Which response do you expect? Which response do you actually get?

Comment: @Kielstra check the update please.

Comment: Are the two missing channels private? I think conversations.list only shows public channels by default.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou no, they are public.

Comment: @mahan were you able to figure this out

Comment: Yes, make sure you do not use `#` as prefix. @SatheeshJM

Comment: huh ok.. 
guess my problem is different.. the list api doesnt event return new channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. Make sure when using channel name, you do not use # as prefix.

```
private fun conversation(name: String): String {
 val channels = client.conversationsList { r -> r.token(slackApiToken).limit(1000) }.channels
 channels.find {it.name == name.removePrefix("#")}?.id ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find channel: $name. Found: ${channels.map { it.name }}")
}


conversation("#slack-bot")
```

If you create new channel, It may take some times before it appears in the list that you fetch.